# Remote connect to MySQL on VPS server using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database-connection, remote-access, vps

i have a problem with connecting the MySQL workbench remotely on my VPS server, and i have not an idea what is the problem...

1. I'm using the cPanel user to connect to the database
2. I have added my current IP to the white list (allowed hosts)
3. I'm using domain name (or server IP) as hostname
4. I'm using default port 3306
5. I got the error 10060

What could be the problem, and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Check to make sure that skip-networking is commented out in the my.cnf. Also, if bind-address is set to 127.0.0.1, comment that line as well.

Comment: Open port 3306 in firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by adding the client IP address to csf.conf file.

Thanks.